# AngularJS to Rails MassAssignmentSecurity::Error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Whilst using AngularJS with Rails I keep getting the MassAssignmentSecurity error whilst updating. I know this is due to passing attributes such as 'created_at' and 'updated_at' along with the data.

To get around this I've been contructing some json which just passes the attributes in the form. This does create more maintenance through the whole program.

Is there a better way to do this?

Here is an example:

AngularJS

```
  $scope.contruct_json = ->
    {
      name: $scope.client.name
      surname: $scope.client.surname
    }


  # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Update
  # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $scope.update = ->
    Client.update
      id: $stateParams['id']
    ,
      client: $scope.contruct_json()
    , (response) ->
      $location.path "/clients/#{$stateParams['id']}"
```

**Update**

Changed my AngularJS code to this

```
  # Remove keys from hash to make it acceptable for Rails to update
  $scope.remove_keys = (hash) ->
    new_hash = {}
    angular.forEach(hash, (value,key) ->
      if(key!='id' && key!='created_at' && key!='updated_at')
        new_hash[key]=value
    ,  new_hash)
    return new_hash
  # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Update
  # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $scope.update = ->
    Client.update
      id: $stateParams['id']
    ,
      client: $scope.remove_keys($scope.client)
    , (response) ->
      $location.path "/clients/#{$stateParams['id']}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you should consider allowing mass assignment for the attributes on your `Client` model with `attr_accessible` ?

Comment: Is it ok to make all attributes accessible?

Comment: generally speaking, no :) i'd be pessimistic about those things and enable only the things you need directly. another option would be to strip those properties out in your controller, say in some `before_filter` or something like that

Answer (score 0):

However you're assigning your attributes, you'll need to declare them as mass-assignable in your model. Try the following:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord
    attr_accessible :created_at, :updated_at # Any attributes you need to make mass-assignable
end
```